# TCP send Stdout to client and read Stdin from client

Tags: go, tcp, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to execute a program remote via a tcp connection
and I want to share the stdout and stdin live between client<>server.

I've the following test server without error handling :p
I know, at the moment I'm not able to execute a program with arguments,
but that's easy to handle :)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":420")
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        // Wait for a connection.
        conn, _ := l.Accept()

        go func(c net.Conn) {
            for {

                msg, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
                program := strings.Trim(msg, "\r\n")

                cmd := exec.Command(program)
                var b bytes.Buffer
                cmd.Stdout = &b
                //cmd.Stdin = &bi
                cmd.Run()
                c.Write([]byte(b.String() + "\n")) //not working
                fmt.Println(b.String())            //working
            }
            //connection closed
            c.Close()
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

You see, I try to share the stdout with c.Write(), but this won't work.

The other problem with cmd.Stdin will be the same problem as Stdout, I think.
At this moment I didn't implement any Stdin-functions.

Could anybody give me a tip or example code for this function?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I try to share stdout with c.Write()"?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, use [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) with `net.Conn` as source and `os.Stdout ` as destination.

Comment: @Flimzy
I mean the following part in my code example: c.Write([]byte(b.String() + "\n"))

Comment: So you just mean that when you write to the network, nothing is received?

Comment: @Flimzy   yes, the client don't recieve the output but the server print the output with fmt.Println(b.String())

Comment: @JohnSPerayil   io.Copy(cmd.Stdout, c) don't work for me. The client don't recieve anything and the server is "hanging" on io.Copy(). After closing the client, the server will print the stdout.

Comment: For better explanation:  'cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout' works fine on serverside, but I want to send this output to the client directly

Comment: it can be interesting to see the error.  n, err := c.Write([]byte(b.String() + "\n")); fmt.Println(n, err)

Comment: @Uvelichitel   The is no error. It returns 2394 <nil>. With the client I send 'ipconfig" to the server (windows pc).

Comment: If I write c.Write([]byte("Test")) after the first with b.String(), the client doesn't recieve any text. (But It works without the b.String() line). It seems that the write process is still open ..

Comment: Try `c.Write([]byte(b.String() + "\r\n"))` (note the added `\r`). depending on the client you are using, this may make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8888")
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        // Wait for a connection.
        conn, _ := l.Accept()

        go func(c net.Conn) {
            for {
                msg, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
                if err != nil {
                    break
                }
                program := strings.Trim(msg, "\r\n")

                cmd := exec.Command(program)
                var b bytes.Buffer
                cmd.Stdout = &b
                cmd.Run()
                conn.Write(b.Bytes())
            }
            //connection closed
            c.Close()
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

**client**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8888")
    for {
        fmt.Print("Command to send: ")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        conn.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s\r\n", text)))
        b := make([]byte, 512)
        conn.Read(b)
        fmt.Println(string(b))
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the same for me. the client don't receive anything (maybe it's a client problem??) But I see, if I send the command 'help' I'll get som characters ...

Comment: @overboarded simple client has been added